# how to login to mongodb in bigbluebutton html5

Tags: linux, networking, mongodb

How do I connect to the installed mongodb?
How many users are defined for mongodb when bbb is installed?

root@srv53607:~# mongo

mongo MongoDB shell version v3.4.22 connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongo 2019-08-15T12:48:25.484+0430 W NETWORK [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused 2019-08-15T12:48:25.484+0430 E QUERY [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:240:13 @(connect):1:6 exception: connect failed root@srv53607:~#

Answer (score 1):

Depending if production or development version of the html5 client.  the url to access the database is different for each.   There is no aithentication by default.

this is with 2.2beta 18 bbb

development
mongo --quiet mongodb://127.0.0.1:3001/meteor --eval "your command"

production
mongo --quiet mongodb://127.0.1.1:27017/meteor --eval "your command"